# force the linux to see less memory than physically accessible

Tags: configuration, memory

Is it possible to force the linux to see less memory than physically accessible?
Context: the system is run inside docker's container with memory limits, but docker doesn't forward these limits into the container, so system processes are not aware of the outside limit, and some greedy processes consume more than allowed and eventually get killed by host oom manager.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mem=size` [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt). This will force the kernel to use only that much memory.

[Restricting memory area for linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25417/restricting-memory-area-for-linux-kernel)